# Divergent monotone sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Is there an example of a divergent monotone sequence with a Cauchy Subsequence that someone could provide? Or is this not possible?

Comment: Think of what a monotone sequence has to do in order to be divergent .

Comment: The answer gives the details to see this.  Your intuition needs to be consulted too.  Consider $\lim_{n\to \infty} s_n=L$ ($L$ finite) and also $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n=  \infty$.  If any sequence has this property (finite or infinite) then so do all its subsequences.  For a nondecreasing sequence you know that either  $\lim_{n\to \infty} s_n$ is finite or it is $+\infty$.  Thus all subsequences behave the same way. [On the real line "Cauchy" and "convergent to a finite limit" say exactly the same thing and are interchangeable.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible.

Let $\{x_n\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a divergent monotonically increasing sequence. (The same argument will work for decreasing sequences since we can take the negative of each term to turn it into an increasing sequence.) Thus $\{x_n\}$ is unbounded above.

Suppose for contradiction that the sequence had a convergent subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$. Denote the limit of the subsequence to be $L$. This subsequence is also increasing, so it is upper bounded by $L$. Since $\{x_n\}$ is unbounded above, we can find some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_m > L$. Then by monotonicity, $n_k < m$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e. $n_k \in \{1,2,\dots,m\}$. But this is impossible since that would imply that there are not infinitely many terms in the subsequence.